# NoSuchClientException, No client with requested id

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

When I try access /oauth/token I got error:

> o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint : Handling error: NoSuchClientException, No client with requested id: username

I got it in next steps:

1. I try to make request oauth/authorize and get popup with inputs credentials.
2. Input it and got error "Unsupportted response_type"
3. Then I try to get token via oauth/token making request

> curl -u clientsecret:12345 -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept:application/json" -d "username=user&password=password&grant_type=password"

And then got this error with NoSuchClientException. Why it set username to clientId?
It's my code:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Inject
    private AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("oauth/token"))
                .disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String CLIENTID = "app";
    private static final String PROP_SECRET = "secret";
    private static final Integer TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = -1;
    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Inject
    private OAuth2AccessTokenRepository oAuth2AccessTokenRepository;

    @Inject
    private OAuth2RefreshTokenRepository oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new MongoDBTokenStore(oAuth2AccessTokenRepository, oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository);
    }

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {

        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENTID)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code","refresh_token","password")
                .authorities("USER", "ADMIN")
                .secret(PROP_SECRET)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create request like this

```
curl app:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token  -d grant_type=password -d client_id=app  -d username=user -d password=password
```